# What's the difference between an empty string and a '\0' char? (from a pointer and array point of view)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

As the title of this question? What's the difference?

If I write:

```
char *cp = "a";
cout << (cp == "a") << endl;
```

or:

```
string str = "a";
cout << (str == "a") << endl;
```

They are the same and all return true.  But if I write:

```
char *cp = "";
cout << (cp == "\0") << endl;
```

It returns false. But:

```
string str = "";
cout << (str == "\0") << endl;
```

It returns true.

I thought they should be the same from the pointer and array perspective. But they turn out to be different. What's the subtle difference between them? And how should I write a char array to represent an empty string?

---

OK, what's above the line might be unclear like somebody said it might be "a compiler optimization".

What I really want is this:

```
char *cp = "abcd";
```

can give me an array like this: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'].
I was wondering how can I use the similar syntax to get an array like this: ['\0'].
Because I tried:

```
char *cp = "";
```

And it seems not the right code. I thought it could give me what I want. But it doesn't.

Sorry for the ambiguousness above the line. I'm a newbie and I don't the that might be a compiler optimization.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by "empty string"? And where is your `'\0'` char?

Comment: You need to learn more about pointer in C. `char` and `std::string` does not the same thing.

Comment: Isn't your first example (`cp=="a"`) only returning true by luck (a compiler optimization I assume)? Use `strcmp()` instead of `==`, and I think it will make more sense.

Comment: You cannot compare C-strings with `==`.

Comment: @juanchopanza For example, I can write `char *cp = "abc"` to represent an array like ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0']. But I want to write something like this `char *cp = ""` to represent something like this ['\0']. How should I do that?

Comment: @ZongyaoJin `""` does represent the array ['\0'].

Comment: `char *cp = "abc"` isn't classic array, it's array in const memory.. And you have a pointer that points to it. Try this:
`char *cp = "abc"; cp[0] = 'd';` and it will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @ZongyaoJin Like this: `char* cp = "";`

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you very much! Could you please look at my new update and give me some suggestions? I really appreciate that.

Comment: @ZongyaoJin No, sorry. I'll file under TL;DR.

Comment: @Z_J Regarding your update to your question, `char *cp = "";` *is* a single byte array containing `\0`. If you are going to use C strings, you need to use the C `strcmp` function to compare them: the `==` on a C string does not compare content the way it does with a C++ `std::string` or strings in Python and most other languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String literals always have an implicit `\0` at the end. So `""` is of type `const char[1]` and consists of one `\0`, whereas `"\0"` is of type `const char[2]` and consists of *two* `\0`s. If you want the empty string literal, just write `""`. There is no need to insert another `\0` manually.

`operator==(const char*, const char*)` compares pointers, not characters. If you compare two different string literals with `==`, the result is guaranteed to be false. (If you compare two string literals consisting of the same characters with `==`, the result is not well-defined.)

`std::string::operator==(const char*)` treats the argument as a C string. That is, it will only read until it encounters the first `\0`. Hence, it cannot distinguish between `""` and `"\0"`.

Comment: Where does it actually say that `"\0"` shall have two elements? Could it be "optimized" to just `""`?

Comment: @zenith Even if the standard allowed that "optimization", would you bother to add that feature to a compiler? The string literal `"\0"` is never used in normal code, so there's no point "optimizing" it.

Comment: 2.14.5 string literals [lex.string] §15 says: "After any necessary concatenation, in translation phase 7 (2.2), `\0` is appended to every string literal so that programs that scan a string can find its end."

Comment: @zenith AFAIK The compiler can do anything that doesn't change the observable behaviour of the program, so it depends on the context in which that literal is used

Comment: @NiklasB. For example, computing `"\0" + 2` must be allowed ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow Thank you very much! Could you please look at my new update and give me some suggestions? I really appreciate that.

Comment: If you have another question, you ask a new question on SO. You don't prepend it to an old question that was already answered.

Answer (score 5):

The `"\0"` actually contains two `'\0'` characters, one of them created implicitly.

If you write something like

```
char *cp = "a";
cout << (cp == "a") << endl;
```

you are comparing two pointers, not the string contents (use `strcmp()` to do so), while

```
std::string cp = "a";
cout << (cp == "a") << endl;
```

compares the contents up to the first found `'\0'`, because the `bool std::string::operator==(const char*)` is overloaded to do so.

---

As for your edits:

> Because I tried:
>
> `char *cp = "";`
>   And it seems not the right code. I thought it could give me what I want. But it doesn't.

```
char* cp = "";
```

isn't exactly the same as

```
char cp[1] = { '\0' };
```

since the string literal is created with static storage location, while the array version allocates memory on the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please look at my new update and give me some suggestions? I really appreciate that.

Comment: @ZongyaoJin One question per question please! I was already pretty annoyed by your 1st edit, because it tended to invalidate the already existing answers. Respect other peoples efforts here please. We're not your personal helpdesk.